# how to properly work with sqlite in a php class

Tags: php, sqlite

how to properly work with sqlite in a class

I want to make a class that, in its methods, must refer to sqlite databases, depending on the parameters.

How to organize these connections correctly?

For example, something like this

```php
class Text {
    private $lang = 'EN';
    private $id;
    private $text;

    public function __construct($lang) {
        GLOBAL $db;

        $this->lang = $lang;
        
        $db = new SQLite3("./$this->lang/text.db");
    }

    public function dbSelectQuery($key) {
        GLOBAL $db;

        $stm = $db->query("SELECT * FROM TEXT WHERE KEY = '$key'");
        $result = $stm->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);

        return $result['text'];
    }

    public function setText($key) {
        $this->text = $this->dbSelectQuery($key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string interpolation `"./{$lang}/text.db"` to select the db by parameter.

i also removed all the globals. You can handle it with an other private variable and don´t need a `GLOBAL`

```php
class Text {
    private $lang = 'EN';
    private $id;
    private $text;
    private $db;

    public function __construct($lang) {
        $this->lang = $lang;
        
        $this->db = new SQLite3("./{$lang}/text.db");
    }

    public function dbSelectQuery($key) {
        $stm = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM TEXT WHERE KEY = '$key'");
        $result = $stm->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);

        return $result['text'];
    }

    public function setText($key) {
        $this->text = $this->dbSelectQuery($key);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's correct way for working with sqlite? Are there any good projects to watch